# Akka Persistence and Mongodb: Persistence failure when replaying events for persistenceId

Tags: mongodb, scala, runtime-error, akka-persistence

I am uisng `akka-persistence` with mongodb using this https://github.com/ironfish/akka-persistence-mongo/ mongodb plugins. when i am running my code, i am getting following error:

```
[ERROR] [11/19/2016 16:47:29.355] [transaction-system-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5] [akka://transaction-system/user/$a] Persistence failure when replaying events for persistenceId [balanceTransactions]. Last known sequence number [0] (akka.persistence.RecoveryTimedOut)
```

I am not getting, what is the meaning of this error and how can i resolve this error. Following is my `reference.conf` file:

```
akka {
  persistence {
    journal {
      plugin = "casbah-snapshot"
    }
    snapshot-store {
      plugin = "casbah-snapshot"
    }
  }
}

casbah-snapshot {
  mongo-url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/user.events"
  woption = 1
  wtimeout = 10000
  load-attempts = 5
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After changing my `reference.conf` file, my example works successfully. Below is valid `reference.conf` file.

```
akka {
  stdout-loglevel = off // defaults to WARNING can be disabled with off. The stdout-loglevel is only in effect during system startup and shutdown
  log-dead-letters-during-shutdown = off
  loglevel = info
  log-dead-letters = off
  log-config-on-start = off // Log the complete configuration at INFO level when the actor system is started

  loggers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger"]
  logging-filter = "akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLoggingFilter"

  persistence {
    journal {
      plugin = "casbah-journal"
    }
  }
}

casbah-journal {
  mongo-url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/transaction.events"
  woption = 1
  wtimeout = 10000
  load-attempts = 5
}
```